# How to substitute several characters in dataframe of strings with one function

Tags: python

I'm trying to substitute some characters in a string by replacing them with "". I'm trying to use lambda function to discard characters in strings that I don't need. Please help me with this problem.

My sample is:

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Goods" :['Chicken eggs','Cowmilk)','Candy-go','Bread','Butter']})
print(df)

Goods
0  Chicken eggs
1      Cowmilk)
2      Candy-go
3         Bread
4        Butter
```

With one lambda replacer it works without question.

```
def replacer():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Goods" :['Chicken eggs','Cowmilk)','Candy-go','Bread','Butter']})
    
    replacer1 = lambda x: x.replace(" ", "")
    df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)
    
    
    return df

replacer()
0    Chickeneggs
1      Cow(milk)
2       Candy-go
3          Bread
4         Butter
Name: Goods, dtype: object
```

But when I want to replace with several lambda replacers, it gives me an error:

```
def replacer():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Goods" :['Chicken eggs','Cowmilk)','Candy-go','Bread','Butter']})
    
    replacer1 = lambda x: x.replace(" ", "")
    replacer2 = lambda x: x.replace(")", "")
    replacer3 = lambda x: x.replace("-", "")
    
    df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)
    df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer2)
    df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer3)
    
    return df

replacer()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b64a731a1bae> in <module>
----> 1 replacer()

<ipython-input-19-d57b1f0a5d24> in replacer()
      7 
      8     df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer2)
----> 9     df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer3)
     10     df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)
     11 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Goods'
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
 Goods
0  Chickeneggs
1      Cowmilk
2      Candygo
3        Bread
4       Butter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For efficiency, I will use vectoring function in Pandas. `.apply` is slow and will get slower with larger data and more characters replacement you add.

A better solution is using `.str.replace` with regular expressions of characters you like to remove. Example:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Goods" :['Chicken eggs','Cow(milk)','Candy-go','Bread','Butter']})

# remove all none words
df['Goods'] = df['Goods'].str.replace('\W+','')
```

### Problem with you code

You are changing the DataFrame in your function call. Modified you `replacer` that you `apply` in Pandas’ series as

```py
def replacer(x):

    # like your func
    x = x.replace(" ", "")
    x = x.replace(")", "")
    x = x.replace("-", "")

     # you could join them and return
     # return x.replace(" ", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")
    
    return x
    
    # apply it to series
    df['Goods'] = df['Goods'].apply(replacer)

    # you can use lambda
    df['Goods'] = df['Goods'].apply(lambda x: x. replace(" ", ""). replace(")", ""). replace("-", ""))
```

But again, using apply is slow. So go for `.str.replace` with regular experessions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Will further use .str.replace() for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this -

```
df = df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)
```

`df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)` replacer returns a pandas Series and you assign it to `df` to the next time you call `replacer2` it tries to apply it to a series and a series does not have a column `Goods`. The solution is -

```
df['Goods'] = df['Goods'].apply(replacer1)
```